# subsonic 3.0.0.3 MVC2 how to work paging Model.HasPreviousPage not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, subsonic3

HI i wish to have some nice paging for my subsonic project, i am fine with the code behind
however i cant find any information with regards to paging on the view side of things ???

i have tried

```
Model.HasPreviousPage
```

but this no longer exists, so am all out of ideas on where to even begin, is there some hidden manual for this stuff somewhere, and activerecord as i really dont like having to come and ask
and would rather there was something i could read and search but for the most up to date stuff.

everything i find seems to be for old versions of MVC or old versions of subsonic or worse a mix of both.

much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay this is what i have done of my own back, i would appreciate some views on if this is viable and acceptable please:

the code behind (Controller)

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        if (!validateInt(page.ToString()))
            page = 0;

        page = page - 1;

        if (page < 0)
            page = 0;

        const int pagesize = 9;

        IQueryable<material> myMaterial = material.All().Where(x => x.category == "Granite").OrderBy(x => x.id);
        var mycount = material.All().Where(x => x.category == "Granite").OrderBy(x => x.id).Count();

        ViewData["numpages"] = mycount / 9;
        ViewData["curpage"] = page;

        return View(new PagedList<material>(myMaterial, page ?? 0, pagesize));

    }
```

the Html

```
showing page <%=Convert.ToInt32(ViewData["curpage"]) + 1 %> of <%=ViewData["numpages"] %><br />
<%
   for (int i = 1; i <= Convert.ToInt32(ViewData["numpages"]); i++)
   {
      %> 

      <span><b><%= Html.ActionLink(i.ToString(),"Index","granite",new{page=i},null) %></b></span>

      <% 
   }
```

%>

the span is just basic, but if this is a good way then i will just style up my spans ???

I cant get this to page though, no matter what i seem to get the same 9 results, am a little confused now !!!

thanks

Comment: it does page, i must be sniffing way too much glue :-)

so how is, is this okay?? is this making good usage of MVC ????

Comment: Thnx fr solution...Can you please explain PagedList ?