# Paging in asp.net-mvc-2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I have been using the excellent [IPagedList from Martijn Boland](http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2008/08/27/paging-with-aspnet-mvc/) paging method for MVC1 for some time now to good effect. I have just attempted to use it with [Haacked's Default Templated Views](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/08/04/default-templated-views.aspx) in MVC2 and have found that it causes problems.

Specifically, when calling:

```
<%= Html.Display("SomeViewDataKeyToAnIPagedListCollection") %>
```

from inside of a Shared Index view, causes the pager object to be rendered instead of the appropriate DisplayTemplate View for the PagedList collection. I assume that this is because the mechanism for matching DisplayTemplates with the Model is falling over.

Anyone come across a workaround for this already?

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to this question (with no real solution):

[MVC2 .NET - Paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536462/mvc2-net-paging)

Here is someone who has implemented paging in MVC2, but without IPageList:

[subsonic 3.0.0.3 MVC2 how to work paging Model.HasPreviousPage not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322826/subsonic-3-0-0-3-mvc2-how-to-work-paging-model-haspreviouspage-not-working)